# Pass Parameters from Serverside to Javascript via HTML file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

How do I pass parameters from a HTML file to a external Javascript file if these parameters are provided to the HTML by the server side (Codeigniter controller)?

In other words, I have parameters that I want to pass from the serverside PHP/Codeigniter to the Javascript file.

**PHP/Codeigniter Serverside Code**

```
function view($id) {

    $data['id'] = $id;    // this is the variable I want to pass to Javascript

    $this->load->view('index', $data);

}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/targetfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $id; ?> //this is how I can retrieve the variable from serverside
...
```

**Javascript (targetfile.js)**

```
var id = id_from_serverside;  // This is where I want the serverside $id to go
```

---

**Additional Info:**

The variable `$id` is grabbed off the url, so for `http://www.domain.com/view/1234`, serverside variable `$id` will be set the value `1234`. This `1234` value will then have to be passed to the javascript file (which does an AJAX call back to the serverside to retrieve data from the database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var id = <?php echo $id; ?> //this is how I can retrieve the variable from serverside
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/targetfile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/targetfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="my_id" value="<?= $id ?>" />
...
```

#### JavaScript

```
var id = $('#my_id').val();
```

---

Try this:

#### PHP/Codeigniter Serverside Code

```
function view($id) {
    echo $id;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$.get('/mycontroller/view', function(data) {
    alert(data);
}, 'html');
```

Skip the `<html><head>...` stuff. Just print the data you need. Then get the data via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am not sure if using AJAX will work in my case. The variable `$id` is grabbed off the url, so for `http://www.domain.com/view/1234`, serverside variable $id will be set the value `1234`. This `1234` value will then have to be passed to the javascript file (which does an AJAX back to the serverside to retrieve data from the database)

Comment: This is an interesting way to accomplish the task :)

Comment: Passing a value from php to js does not require the overhead of ajax -- so it is not ideal for this task.  Generating extra DOM elements to port the data from server-side to client-side will needlessly bloat the script. I don't recommend either of the above techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameters as JSON objects:

```
<?php 
    $object = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true); 
    $encoded_object = json_encode($object); 
    echo '<script>var _page_params = '.$encoded_object.';</script>';
?>
```

will output something like this*:

```
<script>var _page_params = {"foo": "bar", "12": "true"};</script>
```

*disclaimer: Don't have PHP on this machine, so there might be typos* ;)

Comment: Great! Although I am sending only 1 variable now, now I know how to send an array over :)